# Pretty axis labels for log scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try either of the following the axis scale is 1e+03, 1e+06, 1e+09 - is it possible to get nice superscripted 10^3, 10^6, 10^9 instead without resorting to manual labelling?  I seem to recall getting this automatically in the past.

```
qplot(1:10, 10^(1:10))+scale_y_log10()
qplot(1:10, 10^(1:10), log='y')
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `trans_breaks()` and `trans_format()` from library `scales` to get desired formatting of axis values.

```
library(scales)
qplot(1:10, 10^(1:10)) +
     scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
              labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image]

Comment: how could I add dashes between 10 and 1000 (for example 200, 500 and 700) on the y axis ?

Comment: I think what you you are looking for is: "p+ annotation_logticks()"  For reference look at http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotation_logticks.html

Answer (score 8):

You can use `label_log` from the `scales` package:

```r
library(scales)
qplot(1:10, 10^(1:10)) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = label_log())
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. I just want to note that `label_log` was implemented in March 2022 so you will need to make sure your scales package is up to date. Otherwise the older accepted answer will still work.