# ggplot2: Tick labels as base e exponents

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting data on a log-transformed axis, and the default in ggplot is to use the exponent for the tick labels.  However, I would like to include the base e so that tick labels appear as "e^n".  Does anyone know how I can do this?  I can find solutions for base 10 exponents (e.g. [Pretty axis labels for log scale in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178081/pretty-axis-labels-for-log-scale-in-ggplot)), but not for base e.  I've tried modifying the base 10 solution to get base e exponents, but it's not working for me.

This example shows the default behavior:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c(10, 100), y=c(400, 23000))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=log(y)))+geom_line()
```

I can express the tick labels in scientific format using

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=log(y)))+geom_line()+scale_y_continuous(label=scientific)
```

but I instead want these labels to appear as `e^n`. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

EDIT: Didzis's solution worked perfectly, but when using a smaller y-range such as this

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(10, 100), y=c(400, 3000))
```

the ticks are coming up as decimals (e.g. e^6.5) instead of integers (e.g. e^6, e^7).  How can I force ggplot to use just integers?  I've tried

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()+
+     scale_y_continuous(trans="log",breaks = trans_breaks("log", function(x) exp(x), by=1),
+                        labels = trans_format("log", math_format(e^.x)))
```

but that did not work.

EDIT2: I was able to solve this by setting the number of breaks using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()+
scale_y_continuous(trans="log",breaks = trans_breaks("log", function(x) exp(x), n=3),
                   labels = trans_format("log", math_format(e^.x)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `e^n` as labels used `scale_y_continuos()` and then use `trans_breaks()` and `trans_format()` from library `scales` to get desired labels. Also to get log scale use argument `trans="log"` inside the `scales_...` function (do not take `log()` of data inside the `aes()`).

```
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log",breaks = trans_breaks("log", function(x) exp(x)),
                labels = trans_format("log", math_format(e^.x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Didzis!  This is a big step forward, but is there some minor problem with the solution?  For example, the lowest y-value is e^1.8, but this should be e^6. It appears as though your solution is taking natural log of the values, which are already logged.  Instead of "log" should I use another transformation?  I tried "continuous" but it errored.  Thanks!

Comment: Problem was in your example where you took log() of y inside the aes() so range of y values was changed before the plotting. Removing log() from aes() get minumim value as you expect

Comment: Thanks Didzis - OK I see my error.  Your solution works perfectly!  However, when using a smaller y-range, the exponents are appearing as decimals.  I need to reduce the precision - is there a way to do this?  I've updated my original post with an example.   Thanks!

Comment: Dear Didzis - I was able to solve the problem by setting the number of breaks using parameter n in trans_breaks.  Thanks again for your help!