# ggplot2 axis: set intervals, logarithmic scale, and exponents instead of scientific

Tags: r, ggplot2

So first of all, I'm entirely new to programming and R (one week in), so apologies in advance.

How would I format the y axis in the following fashion with ggplot2?:

1. The number of intervals I want. (eg, 10, visually equidistant intervals)
2. Logarithmic scale
3. Exponents instead of scientific (I want 10¹,10²,10³ instead of 1e+01,1e+02,1e+03)

I can find the answers to some of these individual issues, but they don't work in conjunction.

Here's my graph. I don't know if this helps.

ggplot(dfm,aes(Strain,value))+
geom_bar(aes(fill=variable),stat="identity",position="dodge")

Bottom line is:
Currently the y axis is: 1e+02,1e+05,1e+08
I want it to be: 10¹,10²,10³,10⁴,10⁵,10⁶,10⁷,10⁸,10⁹,10¹⁰

Comment: it would be more helpful if you used a builtin dataframe, or provided code to create a minimally reproducible one

Comment: I honestly don't know how. I'm trying to google it at the moment,

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178081/pretty-axis-labels-for-log-scale-in-ggplot) - `library(ggplot2);library(scales);df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=10^(1:100));ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n = 10), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))` for example should get you close. Also read the help `?scales::trans_breaks` etc. to see how to tune all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some guidance (I'm using `tidyr::population` dataset)

1.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)
ggplot(population, aes(country, population)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=year),stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 10))
```

[image]

2.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)
ggplot(population, aes(country, population)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=year),stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

putting it all together:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)
ggplot(population, aes(country, population)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=year),stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  scale_y_log10(labels= trans_format(log10, math_format(10^.x)), 
                breaks =trans_breaks(log10, function(x) 10^x, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!   Context: I originally asked about a log scale, reread the answer (after the edit), assumed I misread the first time, and deleted my comment.