# Scatter plot having high range on Y-axis

Tags: r, plot, graph, scatter-plot

How to make a scatterplot for my data having a huge range for the y axis?
I want to have `year` on X-axis and `Size` on Y-axis while having different colors for years.
The main point in my question is how to show the difference among sizes on y- axis. So, `ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Size)) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(Year)))` would  not be the answer.

```
structure(list(Year = c(2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), Size = structure(c(19L, 
1L, 27L, 27L, 19L, 14L, 23L, 9L, 28L, 14L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 3L, 
23L, 31L, 17L, 18L, 28L, 25L, 5L, 25L, 25L, 13L, 28L, 5L, 15L, 
16L, 7L, 4L, 21L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 25L, 2L, 30L, 33L, 12L, 29L, 11L, 
22L, 25L, 26L, 33L, 25L, 32L, 24L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "100", 
"102", "105", "108", "126", "139", "142", "17", "20", "20 389", 
"200", "25", "27", "30", "300", "35", "40", "43", "44", "46", 
"5 482 ", "50", "500", "507", "52 735 ", "70", "75", "80", "81", 
"83", "95", "96"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-49L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the y axis is too big, with a large range of values, a good option is a logarithmic scale. I will use logarithms base 10 for the y axis scale.

First of all, your data has `Size` as factors, if you read it in as numbers this step will no longer be necessary.

```
df1$Size <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", as.character(df1$Size)))
```

Now the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

Breaks <- min(df1$Year):max(df1$Year)

ggplot(df1, aes(Year, Size, color = factor(Year))) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = Breaks, label = Breaks) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  labs(y = bquote(log[10](Size))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Year"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rui Barradas. How to have to upper limit value on the y- axis? I set the upper value to 100,000 and it totally reshape the whole  graph.

Comment: @EsterSilva You are asking to set an order of magnitude greater. That's a lot, the entire graph will look different. Have you tried `scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 100000))`?

Comment: @EsterSilva See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15178139/8245406) for pretty log scale labels.

Comment: Thanks @Rui Barradas. your comment worked perfect when I edited it to scale_y_log10(limits = c(10, 100000))